# Failed to create database issue with 2.4.1.2. version?

Tags: nuodb

hen creating database in middle of the process giving the archive directory path then finally i will submit the button and i will get the below issue :

**Failed to introduce local node: Starting process [Node SM db=[SampleSuiteDev] pid=4064 id=-1 req=null (local)] would exceed Community Edition license restrictions. Contact support@nuodb.com or visit http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/NuoDB+Editions to upgrade..**

Please give the your valuable response,

Thank in advance, 
Yellappa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Community Edition of NuoDB only supports 'managed' databases.  The 'unmanaged' start/stop process commands are not supported.

Comment: What is the unmanaged databases in Nuoddb ? Can you please explain ?